# sklearn.plot_tree how to visualize class_labels for classification task?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn, tree, decision-tree

I have recently done my trial code on Decision Tree. It is working perfectly fine except for one thing. The tree being plotted does not contain class names in it. Do I do something wrong?

Please see code below and a picture of the data set.

[image]

[image]

```
#Import Data#

import pandas as pd

data_set = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Tree.xlsx")

print(data_set.head())

#Set Features and Training Targets#

features_names=["Money","Debt"]
target_names=["Mood1", "Mood2", "Mood3"]

features = data_set[features_names]
targets = data_set[target_names]

print(features)
print(targets)

#Set Training Set and Test Set#

train_features = features[:10]
train_targets = targets[:10]

test_features = features[10:]
test_targets = targets[10:]

print (train_features)
print (train_targets)

print(test_features)
print(test_targets)

#Estimating Tree#

from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor

dt = DecisionTreeRegressor(max_depth = 3)
dt = dt.fit(train_features, train_targets)

print(dt.score(train_features, train_targets))
print(dt.score(test_features, test_targets))

#Plotting the Tree#

from sklearn import tree
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

tree.plot_tree(dt, feature_names=features_names, class_names=target_names, filled = True)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In regression tasks visualizing labels might not work; the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.plot_tree.html) states that `class_name` parameter is "*Only relevant for classification*".

In this case, your target variable `Mood` could be categorical, representing it's values in a single column. Once this is done, you can set

`tree.plot_tree(clf, class_names=True)`

for symbolic representation of class names

[image]

or

```
class_names = ['setosa', 'versicolor', 'virginica']

tree.plot_tree(clf, class_names=class_names)
```

for the specific class names.

[image]

**Full Example**

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn import tree

iris = load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=0)

clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_leaf_nodes=3, random_state=0)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Symbolic class name representation
tree.plot_tree(clf, class_names=True)

# Specific class name representation
class_names = iris['target_names']

tree.plot_tree(clf, class_names=class_names)
```

Comment: Correct, but OP uses a DT *regressor*, not a classifier. If this applies also to regression settings, please clarify accordingly.

Comment: Well, I had started commenting to the original post that "*this option is not available for regression*", but then I realized that I was not certain about that, so I abandoned the comment; but it seems you have confirmed it indeed :) I suggest you update your post with this clarification (including also the relevant doc link).